# Internals of how JOIN works in the database (SQL, say in MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'd like to find out the internals of how JOINss performed in MySQL. To be exact, the logic, etc. How and in which order it "does" things, including caring of indexes/etc,

Thanks!

Comment: I would start with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770273/database-internals-where-to-begin

Comment: There's a whole host of MySQL internals stuff here: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest first understand how the cartesian product works. Then, go on to understand how join works which is a special case of the cartesian product. Try this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/controlling-optimizer.html